# Mapkit.js reverse geocoding don't give city

Tags: mapkit, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I use Apple Mapkit.js to do some revert geocoding:

```
var geocoder = new mapkit.Geocoder({
    language: "en-GB",
    getsUserLocation: true
}).reverseLookup(new mapkit.Coordinate(48.867119, 2.351231), (err, data) => {
    console.log(data.results[0]);
});
```

But the result from the request only contain the address (in string) and the country, without the city. Do you know if we have any way to do a reverse geocoding and get on what city the coordinate is with Mapkit?

I looked [the documentation of Mapkit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/mapkit/geocoder/2973886-reverselookup) about that, but I don't see any parameter to pass or any way to get the city.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I looked the Mapkit.js client source code, we don't have any others parameters to pass, except the ones described on the documentation. But let's forget “.js”, can we do a reverse geocoding and get the city with the native Mapkit (For iOS/watchOS/…)?
In this case, maybe can we inspect the request sended to Apple server to know how this operation is done by native Mapkit. Thank you.

Comment: were you able to figure out how to get an address object, instead of a formattedAddress string?

Comment: @webdeb Still not today. I moved to another geocoding API, Algolia Places, instead. I still hope Mapkit.js will be able to do that in a near future.